# Display comment count in a view

Tags: views, comments

Using views I would like to display the number of posts by a user. This will include a count of nodes as well as comments.

e.g.

Jon
Nodes: 10
Comments:6

Jane
Nodes: 22
Comments: 9

etc....

I have created a view of type user. I can find the user: content relationship and with aggregation turned on, I can get the node count. However I do not see a user: comment relationship o get the comments that the user has created. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This small Views user: comments relationship patch should be just the ticket: http://drupal.org/node/1773966

> ...I ended up creating a "User: Comments authored" relationship. Very
>   useful. Combined with aggregation and using "count distinct" it allows
>   a user view to include # comments authored and # of nodes authored.

Direct link to patch: http://drupal.org/files/views-uid_comment_relationship.patch